# how to load a class during start up in spring, I am new to spring

Tags: java

how can application itself be `inserted` in `database` during startup only once.

I already tried using `@postconstruct` to do this.

Comment: question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

When using Spring the following are common usage scenario's.

If you are building a web application you add some configuration to `web.xml`, for example ([example for Spring 3](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html)):

```
 <servlet>
   <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>
     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
   </servlet-class>
   <init-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-config.xml</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

This makes sure the Spring application context in the file `/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-config.xml` is loaded when the web application is loaded by the container (e.g. Tomcat). Your application will in this case probably contain of controllers of some sort (classes which handle requests) and these can be set up in spring to be injected with dependencies from the application context.

If you are building a standalone application you need to start it using the `main` method as usual. To load the Spring application context you need to do something like this:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("path/to/applicationContext.xml");
MyApplication app = (MyApplication )context.getBean("myApp");
app.doSomething();
```

This loads the application context from the classpath.